# c# Deserialization not working?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have a test console application, where I am trying to get serializaiton and deserialization to work to store data into an xml file. The serialize method works correctly, but the deserialization doesnt seem to be working. It does not produce any errors but it isnt loading my data from the .xml file. Anyone know why?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList siteList = new ArrayList();
        DeserializeArray();
        siteList.Add("Test 1");
        siteList.Add("Test 2");
        foreach (var item in siteList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        SerializeArray(siteList);
        if (siteList.Contains("Test 2"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2 exists!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static void SerializeArray(ArrayList siteList)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("SiteList.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, siteList);
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    static ArrayList DeserializeArray()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("SiteList.xml");
        ArrayList siteList;
        siteList = (ArrayList)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();

        return siteList;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine (tested), your logic in `Main()` is off - you have to serialize first before deserializing, try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ArrayList siteList = new ArrayList();

    siteList.Add("Test 1");
    siteList.Add("Test 2");
    foreach (var item in siteList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    SerializeArray(siteList);
    siteList = DeserializeArray();
    if (siteList.Contains("Test 2"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 2 exists!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: doesnt this take away the whole point of deserialization? I thought deserialization grabs data from a source. I want to add to the existing .xml file instead of create a new one each time, so shouldn’t I deserialize first?

Comment: if you want to add to an existing XML yes, you can deserialize first - but you have to assign the result to the variable - which you didn't do: `ArrayList siteList  = DeserializeArray();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931484/c-deserializing-but-not-adding-to-previous-xml

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine here. I'm assuming that you have your SiteList.xml from previous run, as you are deserializing first. I added Console.WriteLine to dump the deserialized data for clarity.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList siteList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList deserealizedArray = DeserializeArray();
        foreach (var item in deserealizedArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---");
        siteList.Add("Test 1");
        siteList.Add("Test 2");
        foreach (var item in siteList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        SerializeArray(siteList);
        if (siteList.Contains("Test 2"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2 exists!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static void SerializeArray(ArrayList siteList)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("SiteList.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, siteList);
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    static ArrayList DeserializeArray()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("SiteList.xml");
        ArrayList siteList;
        siteList = (ArrayList)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();

        return siteList;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code only works when a SiteList.xml already exists. Can you please modify it so it works when it doesnt?

Comment: It seems to deserialize now, however when new data is serialized it is not added into the new arraylist? It overwrites the existing list with the new data? Any Ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you are creating a new list in your code and serializing it. You need to change your code so that you add elements to the list you just deserialized and then serialize *that* list.